# Relative layout not filling inside a toolbar xml

Tags: android, xml

I am creating an android app with the custom toolbar. Whenever I am adding a relative layout to it with match parent, It shows a couple of padding.  Then I googled the problem and find the solution "ContentInset". But my app is still showing the padding.

code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/a_color_bg_hash"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mytextview1"
                    android:layout_width="178.3dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/title1"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/line"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/close_btn"
                    android:background="@color/a_color_bg_hash" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:id="@+id/close_btn"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your code works perfect for me. Try rebuild clean and restart

Comment: It should work . Add the style you are using .

Comment: Can you post your Screensort image of toolbar

Comment: Where you find unwanted padding? vertical or horizontal?  android:padding="20dp" will add padding of 20dp to all the four boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution. That is removing `Toolbar` and its layout and use our own custom layout. It acts like a `Toolbar`. Then we don't have to worry about padding or margin issues.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you do not use any layout inside `Toolbar`

Here is my toolbar that is working fine

**toolbar_layout.xml**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/home_layout_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp">

            <com.cdnsol.cdnshow.widget.StyledTextView
                android:id="@+id/title_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Match your code with this, hope it will help you.

## Edit

With your current code try to replace your RelativeLayout's property with this

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
```

Comment: what is your theme defined in Manifest for this Activity, is it Actionbar theme or NoActionBar...?

Comment: I have to use `match_parent` in `RelativeLayou`, Thanks.

Comment: `<activity
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:name=".activities.DataPreviewTableActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar"/>`